# How to get the distance between two points and move one point along the line to reach the other

Tags: java, swing, math, point

I am trying to move a point(100,100) to another point(450,500). To do this I got the distance between the points by subtracting: `int dx = x2 - x1` and then subtracting: `int dy = y2 - y1`. I get 1% of of `dy (dy / 100) * 1;` and 1% of `dx (dx / 100) * 1;`. Then I add the 1% of each to x1 and y1 in order to move the point along the JFrame to reach the second point.

For some reason when I move the point in the `tick()` method it misses the second point. I have tried numerous different ways to achieve this. I assume it's a mathematical miscalculation or I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Distance extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private int x1, y1;
    private int x2, y2;
    private int width, height;

    private int dx, dy;

    public Distance() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(850, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        x1 = y1 = 100;
        x2 = 450;
        y2 = 500;
        width = height = 20;

        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, width, height);
        g.fillOval(x2, y2, width, height);
        repaint();
    }

    private void tick() {
        int moveX = (dx / 100) * 1;
        int moveY = (dy / 100) * 1;
        x1 += moveX;
        y1 += moveY;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                tick();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Distance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `double`s instead of `int`s, otherwise, you're loosing precision.

Since `fillOval` only takes `int` as parameters, you have to cast them but don't worry, it doesn't affect the rendering.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Distance extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private double x1, y1;
    private double x2, y2;
    private double width, height;

    private double dx, dy;

    public Distance() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(850, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        x1 = y1 = 100;
        x2 = 450;
        y2 = 500;
        width = height = 20;

        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)width, (int)height);
        g.fillOval((int)x2, (int)y2, (int)width, (int)height);
        repaint();
    }

    private void tick() {
        double moveX = (dx / 100) * 1;
        double moveY = (dy / 100) * 1;
        x1 += moveX;
        y1 += moveY;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                tick();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Distance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Should of realized that

Comment: totally wrong answer, explanations 1. `repaint();` inside `paint` can creates infinite loop, 2. `repaint` should be called out of custom code block and to the `container`, 3 in `21th.century` is `JPanel` used as container for `Custom painting`, 4. 1st. code line should be `super.paint(Component)`, 5. by using `Swing Timer`, because `Thread.sleep(100);` can lock `EDT`, until `while(true) {` ended, doesn't matter if is there `repaint` or not, 6 code valid for Java 2 - 3 (10-15 years back)

Comment: @mKorbel Question was `How to get the distance between two points and move one point along the line to reach the other` So, no, the answer wasn't "totally wrong"